# How do you handle your data backend as DM?

Tags: dnd-5e, tools, new-gm, gm-preparation

I'm a brand new DM with zero experience in the field, though I have played a few campaigns as a player. My first campaign is almost finished, at least for the plot/writing/arc parts. My problem now is: how do I set it up at the table?

To make a very long story as short as possible, here's what I wanna do (and don't know how to): I need a software solution for my data back end in session. I don't do online sessions with my group, we're old fashioned that way. My setup is my DM screen, my books, my minis, my props and my laptop. The laptop should be there for notes and tables. And that's where the problem starts.

I need some kind of notation software to manage sessions, to serve as a kind of wiki for my world building, lore, zettelkasten/database for NPCs and to quickly throw a dialogue scene or a random encounter together if needed. All the front end stuff, like dice rolls, initiative tracker and combat stuff I can do manually.

Here's a use case scenario: My party decides to go off the beaten path. At a fork in the road they decide to go neither left nor right, but through the woods in a southern direction. I know that this will lead them into tribe territory. While I let the scout roll for stealth and perception, I wanna quickly look up the lore of the southern faction of the tribespeople that I wrote a few nights earlier into my campaign-wiki. Since the scout rolled really badly, I immediately call for initiative and type the name of the tribe into my software. I pull out some prepared stat blocks for a barbarian, two archers and a druid of said tribe. During combat I choose the appropriate loot table from my templates or improvise. Since all the data is on my laptop, I avoid losing ten minutes skimming trough a few dozen pieces of paper in four different binders and kill the mood of the session while two of the players go outside for a cigarette and another starts a phonecall.

That's the dream. Up until this moment I wasted two weeks trying to learn Obsidian.md, which seemed to offer the perfect solution (interconnected notes, quickly linkable pages/paths, zettelkasten principle, clear data structure,...), but all the tutorial people on YouTube are overshooting my goals by a mile and a half. I need data management and quick accessibility, not a sentient A.I. running online campaigns on it's own on four different monitors (sorry for the exaggerations, it's kinda my thing). I'm no tech genius. I can't code shit.

How do you handle this? Is there already a solution for this problem? Where do I start? How do I keep it simple without losing comfort and versatility?

Comment: Welcome to the stack Wurzel Sepp, take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you have a moment, and feel free to peruse the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more in-depth info about the site.

Comment: A couple of suggestions.  You might want to mention the version you are playing.  Maybe it won't matter to the answer, but it might.  Also, mentioning your experience with Obsidian is extremely helpful.  You might be able to improve your question by noting any other tools you've tried and discarded, and even if there are any tools that you **do** use that might be related.  For instance, if you do or don't use a spreadsheet or a notes program, those bits of  information might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! As of now, I do not use any tools or spreadsheets yet. My campaign is currently organized for writing and rewriting/reviewing (like a script for a book). Now I wanna reorganize the big blocks of text into a easily accessible, quick to use data format like a wiki. Obsidian looked great, but I failed at using plugins and templates, cause the overall best practice solutions for ttrpgs are more about automation than data management. The software itself would be able to solve my problem, I'm just too stupid to write my own templates and code my own plugins.

Comment: Any other tools that I briefly looked at are either not free to use (Kanka) or extremely oversized for my needs (WorldAnvil). I might be wrong though. As a beginner I rely on guessing rather than experience. Also, this is about dnd5e, but I don't think it matters for the software.

Comment: Updating your question for what you've said in comments might be helpful.  For instance, you mentioned Kanka.  If you've evaluated that, you want to say what was or was not useful.  You mentioned that free-to-use is important.  It's worth updating your question with that.  Also, I see that Kanka has a free tier, and for that matter their first paid tier is  $5/month.  If that's out of your budget, it's good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Obsidian Portal: old but for purpose

I have used a number of different methods over the years, and while I’ve now migrated to a very low-prep heavily improvised style, I did use to document world and session notes in a lot of detail. Aside from detailed Google docs that were just for me, the best tool I found for documentation was [Obsidian Portal](https://www.obsidianportal.com/) (whose name is similar to Obsidian only by coincidence as far as I know).

It’s pretty much exactly what you describe wanting: a wiki for roleplaying games. It has templates for many popular games to help you write up character sheets and stats, and built-in categorisation of a campaign into locations, characters and dated session notes. Its free version includes all the main features, but limits you to two separate campaigns, a small amount of storage for file uploads, and does not include the ability to create secret notes invisible to the players. Also of note for you, the free version cannot be made private, but there’s nothing to stop you using it to organise your notes and just not telling the players about it.

If it seems a bit too old-fashioned (and it is getting a bit long in the tooth, in internet and wiki terms), there are similar newer solutions. I’ve not tried those, but the preeminent one seems to be World Anvil, though I note from your comments it was probably too complex for what you want.

### Twine: not intended for this use but free and flexible

Another free solution could be [Twine](https://twinery.org). I’ve used this text-based game creation engine to model branching narratives in many contexts, including for what were effectively large-scale live roleplaying games, though I haven’t used it for tabletop games. Games are organised into passages, which can link to each other in any way you like. When you export the Twine game you get an HTML file with hyperlinks. It would be easy to create a Twine which models the various scenes in a planned campaign and following it through as you play, and it could easily link to external URLs like encounters or stat blocks in D&D Beyond etc.

Answer (score 2):

### How do *I* handle my data backend?

[image: Notebooks]

Technically, those are my son’s notebooks, but I do it the same way. Please note the closed and unplugged laptop.

It’s an ancient technique developed by the Egyptians called writing things down on paper. Again, technically, they used papyrus (I know this audience - someone will say this if I don’t).